# Read excel file from AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I have a method to read an excel file that is on my local machine using filename path like this:

```
               // Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
               Console.WriteLine("Begin reading file...");
               Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
               Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\file1.xlsx");
               Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
               Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
               // Some code here
```

Now I have to read the file from an AWS S3 bucket, and I'm pretty new to the whole AWS environment. From all the sources I read I think the file you get from a S3 bucket only can be returned as "stream" type.

How do I make it work with my current method?

Is there other better way to do this, my goal is just read an excel file from a S3 bucket and do something with the data inside.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do. Here's a couple

1. You can save the blob as a local file. [Docs from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html)
2. You can use third party to mount your bucket as a virtual Drive. [Check here](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/drive/amazon-s3.aspx). Keep in mind you're making your operations across the network here.
3. You may also just skip the COM objects alltogheter and use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML). This will avoid the speed and memory issues currently available with COM. This will also give you the flexibility to move it to lambda or containerized services since you're already working with AWS.

I'm sure you're aware by now, one thing you'll need to watch out for is the file permission while your process is working with the file.